# Both the conditions are not getting satisfied. While using this "when" multi-condition in my ansible task

Tags: ansible, task

```yaml
when: >
      ansible_os_family != "Windows" and (item != 'ccproot' or item != 'ccpadmin')
```

Both the conditions are not getting satisfied. While using this `when` multi-condition in my Ansible task.

Comment: Well, this is always true, because item can't be both ccproot and ccpadmin at the same time: `item != 'ccproot' or item != 'ccpadmin'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is in the logic you are trying to apply. As James Z stated, you are trying to evaluate if a variable is different to cproot or cpadmin, if its cpadmin cproot will be distinct and if the variable is cproot, cpadmin will be distinct
Maybe this make more sense to you:

```yaml
when: ansible_os_family != "Windows" and item != "ccproot" and item != "ccpadmin"
```

This way you are analyzing if the variable is different to the 3 values.